# How to 'view' a Form.Designer.cs file visually?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am following a video tutorial for a .NET application.
This is my first .NET application so I am very new to this.
I downloaded the tutorial project given in the video.
In the video, the tutor is able to view the form.designer.cs file visually and 'see' the actual UI and rearrange the buttons, drag and drop new objects etc.

For me it just shows the code view when I click on the form.designer.cs file. How can I shift to the drag-drop UI view?

I have a MAC OSx. Furthermore, in terms of file structure, I have a Form1.cs file and when I click on that in VS Studio, I get a down arrow with Form1.resx and Form1.Designer.cs file inside it.

Comment: What type of project are you attempting to create? Also, what version of Visual Studio are you using? VS for Mac 2019? VSCode on Mac OSx?

Comment: Go to menu View : Solution Explorer. You will will see form in the explorer.  Double click on form bring up view automatically.

Comment: It's a .NET core Console Application. It's Visual Studio 2019 for Mac.

Comment: There is no option 'Solution Explorer' in the View menu. The closest is 'Solution' under 'Layouts' . But clicking on 'Solution' does nothing.

Comment: Windows Forms isn't supported on a Mac - you'll need to switch to Windows instead.

Comment: Ohkay. Does this mean that I can work on Forms but can't see them visually in Mac OR I cannot work on Forms altogether on a Mac?

Answer (score -2):

Push Shift+F7, which is the shortcut to open the designer. You should also be able to access it using the Solution Explorer on the right-hand side of your VS environment.

Comment: This answer ignores the fact that the user in question is on a Mac and therefore cannot work with WinForms at all.